# QGIS shows incorrect $area in label, but correct in field calculator

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area

I tried showing `$area` of polygons in QGIS, and it always showed planimetric square degrees instead of metric units. No matter what I set in project general settings, the value remained the same.

QGIS version is 3.4.3, layer CRS is 4326, and I tried different CRS in the project, which made no difference.

I calculated a new field with the formula: `$area / 10000` (to get hectares, which is more readable). And [looking it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novosibirsk) in Wikipedia, the city area is close to that and is rather correct.

So, you can get `$area` but have to use field calculator. Is there a workaround to make `$<function>` work correctly in labels?

[image]

Following suggestions by @MAP: the derived tab in object properties is always correct...

[image]

...But the reason I'm asking is that the function description promises to work this way too:

[image]

...while simple `area(geometry)` is always planimetric.

Comment: Which CRS (EPSG) uses your QGIS project? (as shown down right in the status bar)

Comment: @MAP: it's 3857. Changing it also does not make any difference.

Comment: Try: Compare the results in the "derived" tab in the Identify Results window for one country. There are two calculations based on ellipsoidal / cartesian surface

Comment: @MAP I did, those are always correct.

Comment: It seems that the `area(geometry)` function in the label expression ignores the properties of the project but of the layer. It can be solved with the `transform(geom, source_auth_id, dest_auth_id)` function. What version of QGIS are you using? What is the coordinate reference system of the layer?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca version is 3.4.3, layer CRS is 4326.

Comment: If the `area` function is behaving inconsistently, that's a big problem! Please [make a bug report](https://issues.qgis.org) ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I also see that the function always calculates the planimetric area in the labeling.

A possible solution (I do not consider it robust but at least possible) is to reproject the polygons in the *World_Cylindrical_Equal_Area* CRS (*EPSG:54034*).

Since the spatial reference of the vector layer is the geographic system *WGS 84* (*EPSG: 4326*), the `transform` function can be included in the labeling expression to reproject the geometry and calculate the area at the time of labeling:

```
'$area in calculator:' || ar || '\n$area in label:' || round( area( transform( $geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:54034') ) / 10000, 4)
```